# Reference variables stated in other classes

Tags: ios

It's a very basic question.
In `AppDelegate.m`,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.stationInfos = [StationDB database].stationInfos;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and I want to be able to use `stationInfos` from inside my `ViewController.m`. What is the most conventional way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you just call `[StationDB database].stationInfos` from your view controller?

Comment: There might be other classes that need `stationInfos`. In that case is it the right decision to have it in `AppDelegate.m` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would state that it is generally frowned upon to store such data in the AppDelegate (either the .m or .h file).

If you need to access the data from multiple places, then a Singleton object is generally the recommended approach. A singleton is an object-oriented concept where only a single instance of an object is maintained in order to allow access from multiple locations to the same data source.

Or, if [StationDB database].stationInfos is already a singleton (I'm not familiar with the object), then it's possible you might be able to just access it anywhere you need it. There's nothing that says you need to define it in the .h or the .m file - you can define it just in the method where it is needed as well.

General guidelines might be:

- Define in .h >> If a limited # of other objects may need to access it.
- Define in .m >> If only that class needs to access it.
- Define in a specific method >> If only that method needs to access it.
- Define as a Singleton >> If many objects need to access it.
- **Don't** >> Define it in the AppDelegate. It's best to place your logic in your appropriate model, view, or controller class files.

Answer (score 1):

You would set variable up in the .h instead of the .m. From there, inside your ViewController.m you should import the AppDelegate.h.

Then, when you want the variable do:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
variableType *stationInfos = appDelegate.stationInfos;
```

Comment: In ViewController, is it a good idea to store appDelegate variable as one of its properties `self.delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` if I use delegate's methods and properties across the methods?

Comment: You can do that, but don't call it delegate, that's partly reserved or will cause issues.

Comment: More specifically, if I use appDelegate object in two methods A and B, should I get the delegate object inside from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: That's fine, but make sure you don't get a strong retain loop. Make it a weak reference